# What goes on the stack and what goes on the heap in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am really confused about Rust's system of memory allocation.

In Java you use `new` to allocate memory on the heap. In C you use `malloc()`, everything else goes on the stack.

I thought, in Rust, `Box<T>` allocates memory on the heap but after reading ["Defining Our Own Smart Pointer" section in chapter 15.2 in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#defining-our-own-smart-pointer) it seems like `MyBox<T>` doesn't have any special annotation to make the value of `T` live on the heap.

1. What exactly goes on the stack and what goes on the heap?
2. Is the implementation of `MyBox<T>` essentially the same as `Box<T>`?
3. If the implementations are identical, what makes `T` stored on the heap rather than the stack?
4. If the implementations aren't identical what makes a `Box<T>` allocate memory on the heap?

Comment: (Actually, in C, these is no concept of heap or stack, malloc is only require to give memory, whatever it is, some implementation of malloc use "the stack", but C doesn't care, and that is the point, C abstract this for you (however under the hood malloc often use "the heap"))

Comment: Try not to think of "stack" vs. "heap" as those two concepts are really antiquated and mostly irrelevant since compilers can and will blur those lines really heavily. Think instead of "local" vs. "shareable" or "dynamic".

Comment: Yeah I do think this way, I just want to know what is happening under the hood and how rust accomplishes that without an explicit call to something like "new"

Comment: It is preferred to post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question as well as others hunting for one of your questions.

Comment: @JimMorrison: About question 3-4: The book you link to states the following: "*Note: there’s one big difference between the MyBox<T> type we’re about to build and the real Box<T>: our version will not store its data on the heap.*" So the `MyBox` and the regular `Box` are fundamentally different!

Comment: If a type uses heap in Rust, it will involve [`std::alloc::Allocator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html) I guess?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. This is hard to say. Usually Rust avoid allocating anything on the heap. Never will the compiler do an implicit allocation on the heap, but may library functions can do it for you. At least anything that is dynamically sized (eg. `Vec<T>`) will need something on the heap under the hood, for the rest, the documentation should hint it.

   Note that even in C, many functions can do heap allocation without an explicit call to `malloc`. Eg. I've had to debug a memory leak recently where a developer called [`getaddrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) without a corresponding `freeaddrinfo`, ignoring that this function allocates memory on the heap. This class of bugs should be really rare in Rust however, thanks to [RAII](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html?highlight=RAII#memory-and-allocation).
2. Not at all! The book is simplifying things here to avoid details not important for this section.
3. —
4. `Box` is a compiler built-in. Under the hood what allocates the memory is an allocator defined as in [`liballoc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/). You can think of this allocator as providing `malloc`-like functionality. In practice, the default allocator uses [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) on most targets, it is also possible to use a custom allocator, for example the [`alloc_system`](https://crates.io/crates/alloc_system) crate uses the system's `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` functions to build its allocator.

Comment: That's actually what I thought (that Box gets a "special treatment") but I couldnt find anything online that confirms this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Jim The only special thing about how `Box` handles memory is that you can use `*` to move out of it (deallocating the backing memory). Everything else about `Box` can be and is written in ordinary Rust code using `liballoc` as a backend.

Comment: See cs242.stanford.edu/f19/lectures/07-2-smart-pointers for details on implementing simplified Box, Rc using raw pointers and traits

Comment: _sneaks away to add freeaddrinfo because I think I made that same mistake a week ago and didn't know_

Answer (score 0):

Just for setting the record straight, malloc is heap, new is heap. Stack allocation doesn't require any malloc, and the malloc can just be liberated through a free, the same for the new can only be liberated by a deleted; otherwise you get a process leak. In those languages, the developer manages what is stack allocation and heap allocation.
For the question, the Box::new goes in the heap. The memory is claimed back with Box::Drop (you don't see this), unless you transfer ownership.
To complement --> types that have a known size at compile time are stored entirely on the stack. This tells you that Rust is managing what goes on the stack and what goes on the heap. Rust ownership and borrowing should clarify this.